# Does anyone have a good web audio api drum machine tutorial?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I want to get a better understanding of web audio api, and I would like to build something like this http://stuartmemo.com/beat-petite but I can't really find any good starting points. There are plenty of great drum machines online, but I don't really know where to begin! Any help in finding one would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The best starting point would be to learn how to play back an audio sample. Then you will probably have to abstract the code as its a bit bulky. From there you can learn scheduling and timing events.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article on scheduling (used for sequencing and drum beats) - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.  Read that, then just start pulling apart the code to a drum machine like Stuart's.

Comment: I read two or three times that article, and i'm still having troubles. I don't know if it is because i suck at english, but my brain just don't "click".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library which I have written : https://github.com/sebpiq/WAAClock

It lets you schedule things precisely and easily and also provides useful functionalities such as : cancel event, change tempo, ... everything necessary for a drum machine. There is actually a demo of building a very simple drum machine with WAAClock there : https://github.com/sebpiq/WAAClock/tree/master/demos